# Split text file into Strings on empty line

Tags: java, regex, split

I want to read a local txt file and read the text in this file. After that i want to split this whole text into  Strings like in the example below .

Example :
 Lets say file contains-

```
 abcdef                                 
 ghijkl

 aededd               
 ededed

 ededfe
 efefeef
 efefeff

 ......
 ......
```

I want to split this text in to Strings

```
s1 = abcdef+"\n"+ghijkl;

s2 = aededd+"\n"+ededed; 

s3 = ededfe+"\n"+efefeef+"\n"+efefeff;

........................
```

I mean I want to split text on empty line.

I do know how to read a file. I want help in splitting the text in to strings

Comment: Are you sure that reading the whole file then splitting such a long string is a good idea? I'd suggest you instead reading by lines, append them to ``StringBuilder`` through ``\n`` until have read blank line.

Comment: `string.split("\n\r")`
Find this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717667/how-to-split-string-with-empty-new-line)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can split a string to an array by

```
String.split();
```

if you want it by new lines it will be

```
String.split("\\n\\n");
```

**UPDATE***

If I understand what you are saying then john.

then your code will essentially be

```
BufferedReader in
   = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.txt"));

List<String> allStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
String str ="";
while(true)
{
    String tmp = in.readLine();
    if(tmp.isEmpty())
    {
      if(!str.isEmpty())
      {
          allStrings.add(str);
      }
      str= "";
    }
    else if(tmp==null)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
       if(str.isEmpty())
       {
           str = tmp;
       }
       else
       { 
           str += "\\n" + tmp;
       }
    }
}
```

Might be what you are trying to parse.

Where allStrings is a list of all of your strings.

Comment: I think the pattern should be \\n\\n for double lines.

Comment: not on new line i want to split strings on empty line because String can be any number of lines.

Comment: Please see the updated question String can be any number of line.

Comment: This answer will work, since it only splits when it finds two newlines (e.g. a blank line).

Comment: @johnsmith I have updated my answer, but please be aware this is not tested

Comment: Thanks for your effort it is working but need some modification. i'll make these changes, thanks once again.

Comment: Thanks for the code. There are 3 changes: 1. The if check for (tmp==null) should come first, otherwise there will be a null pointer exception. 2. This code leaves out the last set of lines being added to the ArrayList. To make sure the last one gets added, we have to include this code after the while loop: if(!str.isEmpty()) { allStrings.add(str); }. 3. The line str += "\\n" + tmp; should be changed to use \n instead if \\n. Please see the end of this thread, I have added the entire code so that it can help

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest more general regexp:

```
text.split("(?m)^\\s*$");
```

In this case it would work correctly on any end-of-line convention, and also would treat the same empty and blank-space-only lines.

Answer (score 6):

The below code would work even if there are more than 2 empty lines between useful data.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

// read your file and store it in a string named str_file_data

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\n[\\n]+");     /*if your text file has \r\n as the newline character then use Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\r\\n[\\r\\n]+");*/
String[] result = p.split(str_file_data);
```

(I did not test the code so there could be typos.)

Answer (score 4):

It may depend on how the file is encoded, so I would likely do the following:

```
String.split("(\\n\\r|\\n|\\r){2}");
```

Some text files encode newlines as "\n\r" while others may be simply "\n". Two new lines in a row means you have an empty line.

Comment: This one falsely splits on `\r\n` and therefore doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Godwin was on the right track, but I think we can make this work a bit better. Using the '[ ]' in regx is an or, so in his example if you had a \r\n that would just be a new line not an empty line. The regular expression would split it on both the \r and the \n, and I believe in the example we were looking for an empty line which would require a either a \n\r\n\r, a \r\n\r\n, a \n\r\r\n, a \r\n\n\r, or a \n\n or a \r\r

So first we want to look for either \n\r or \r\n twice, with any combination of the two being possible.

```
String.split(((\\n\\r)|(\\r\\n)){2}));
```

next we need to look for \r without a \n after it

```
String.split(\\r{2});
```

lastly, lets do the same for \n

```
String.split(\\n{2});
```

And all together that should be

`String.split("((\\n\\r)|(\\r\\n)){2}|(\\r){2}|(\\n){2}");`

Note, this works only on the very specific example of using new lines and character returns. I in ruby you can do the following which would encompass more cases. I don't know if there is an equivalent in Java.

```
.match($^$)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kevin code works fine and as he mentioned that the code was not tested, here are the 3 changes required:

1.The if check for **(tmp==null)** should come first, otherwise there will be a null pointer exception.

2.This code leaves out the last set of lines being added to the ArrayList. To make sure the last one gets added, we have to include this code after the while loop: **if(!str.isEmpty()) { allStrings.add(str); }**

3.The line **str += "\n" + tmp**; should be changed to use **\n** instead if **\\n**. Please see the end of this thread, I have added the entire code so that it can help

```
BufferedReader in
   = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.txt"));

List<String> allStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
String str ="";
List<String> allStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        String str ="";
        while(true)
        {
            String tmp = in.readLine();
            if(tmp==null)
            {
                break;
            }else if(tmp.isEmpty())
            {
                if(!str.isEmpty())
                {
                    allStrings.add(str);
                }
                str= "";
            }else
            {
                if(str.isEmpty())
                {
                    str = tmp;
                }
                else
                {
                    str += "\n" + tmp;
                }
            }

        }
        if(!str.isEmpty())
        {
            allStrings.add(str);
        }
```