# How to split string with empty new line

Tags: java, string

my file contains this string:

```
a

b

c
```

now I want to read it and split it with empty line so I have this:

```
text.split("\n\n"); where text is output of file
```

problem is that this doesnt work. When I convert new line to byte I see that "\n\n" is represented as 10 10 but new line in my file is represented by 10 13 10 13. So how I can split my file ?

Comment: Can you post an output of what you need? Or are you just trying to copy the input to the output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Escape  Description            ASCII-Value
\n      New Line Feed (LF)     10
\r      Carriage Return (CR)   13
```

So you need to try `string.split("\n\r")` in your case.

#### Edit

If you want to split by *empty line*, try `\n\r\n\r`. Or you can use `.readLine()` to read your file, and skip all empty lines.

Are you sure it's `10 13 10 13`? It always should be `13 10`...

And, you should not depend on `line.separator` too much. Because if you are processing  some files from *nix platform, it's `\n`, vice versa. And even on Windows, some editors use `\n` as the new line character. So I suggest you to use some high level methods or use `string.replaceAll("\r\n", "\n")` to normalize your input.

Comment: I think he left out the leading 0x13. Windows line endings are CARRIAGE RETURN followed by LINE FEED. (\r\n). Unless somebody is playing a joke on the guy and the lines are separated by `\n\r` like on the Acorn BBC (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBC_Micro)

Comment: and how I can get '\r\n' independeet from os ? System.getProperty("line.separator")  gives me just \n

Comment: @hudi You should not depend on `line.separator` too much. Because if you process some file from *nix, it's `\n`, vice versa. And even on Windows, some editors use `\n` as the new line character.

Comment: you are rigth it is 13 10 my mistake

Comment: I had to do this in js. \n\r\n\r did the trick for me when nothing else did.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind, sometimes you have to use:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

to get the line separator, if you want to make it platform independent. You can also use [BufferedWriter's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine%28%29) newLine() method, that takes care of that automatically.

Comment: when I convert System.getProperty("line.separator"); to byte is return just 13 so I cant split it by NEWLINE + NEWLINE

Comment: there's difference in what that method returns, depending on the OS - that's the whole point... Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
text.split("\n\r");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you splitting on `\n\n`?

You should be splitting on `\r\n` because that's what the file lines are separated by.

Comment: hm ok and how I can split this file indipendent from os ? System.getProperty("line.separator") gives me just \n

Answer (score 0):

Try to use regular expressions, something like:

```
text.split("\\W+");
```

```
text.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: `"a b c\r\n\r\nd".split("\\s+")` returns `["a", "b", "c", "d"]`, it does not fit OP's requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
LF: Line Feed, U+000A
CR: Carriage Return, U+000D

so you need to try to use  
"string".split("\r\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) object, instead of worrying about chars/bytes.

Answer (score -1):

One Solution is to Split using "\n" and neglect empty Strings

```
List<String> lines = text.split("\n");

for(String line : lines) {
  line = line.trim();
  if(line != "") {
      System.out.println(line);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's telling me `split` returns `String[]`. And why do you compare strings using `!=`?