# Java Substring from multiline string

Tags: java, substring

I having one requirement to edit the string and  display

Input string :

> Invite URL: www.someurl.com id:12345678 dial:+98765432 code:0192837465
>   AccessCode: 12345 password:abc

some line here

i do not want to show the last 3 lines,

I tried to search the index of empty lines and get the substring from index 0 to empty line index

```
int index = mystring.indexof(("\\r\\n")); 

mystring.substring(0,index)
```

however index is always returning -1. my doubt is how to find the index for empty string.

i wanted the substring till AccessCode or Password(Either Both AccessCode and Password will be present or only AccessCode will be present) from InviteURL , any other additional line after that I have to skip

Output expected:

> Invite URL: www.someurl.com
>   id:12345678
>
> dial:+98765432
>
> code:0192837465
>
> password:abc

Comment: Read all lines into an ArrayList<String> variable then loop until length - 3?

Comment: Using `String.trim()` or `String.strip()`,  or just `Streams.lines` to filter the last 3 lines

Comment: Refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065885/split-text-file-into-strings-on-empty-line

Comment: `int index = mystring.indexof(("\\r\\n")); ` be instead of `int index = mystring.indexof(("\\n\\n")); `

Answer (score 2):

There is a number of ways to accomplish this but the easiest is most likely:

```
String inputString ="URL: www.someurl.com\n" +
                    "id:12345678\n" +
                    "dial:+98765432\n" +
                    "code:0192837465\n" +
                    "password:abc\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n" +
                    "some line here\n" +
                    "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~";

if (inputString.contains("\r\n")) {
    inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.indexOf("\r\n\r\n")).trim();
}
else {
    inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.indexOf("\n\n")).trim();
}
System.out.println(inputString);
```

Another simple way to accomplish this is:

```
String inputString ="URL: www.someurl.com\n" +
                    "id:12345678\n" +
                    "dial:+98765432\n" +
                    "code:0192837465\n" +
                    "password:abc\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n" +
                    "some line here\n" +
                    "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~";
String[] stringParts = inputString.split("\n\n|\r\n\r\n");
inputString = stringParts[0];
System.out.println(inputString)
```

And yet another way this can be accomplished is by utilizing the Scanner class:

```
String inputString ="URL: www.someurl.com\n" +
                    "id:12345678\n" +
                    "dial:+98765432\n" +
                    "code:0192837465\n" +
                    "password:abc\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n" +
                    "some line here\n" +
                    "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputString);
String line;
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    line = scan.nextLine();
    if (line.equals("")) {
        break;
    }
    sb.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
}
inputString = sb.toString().trim();
System.out.println(inputString);
```

If you want to use a [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (RegEx) along with [Pattern/Matcher](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html) classes which is part of the **java.util.regex** package then you can try this:

```
String inputString = "URL: www.someurl.com\n"
                   + "id:12345678\n"
                   + "dial:+98765432\n"
                   + "code:0192837465\n"
                   + "password:abc\n"
                   + "\n"
                   + "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n"
                   + "some line here\n"
                   + "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?\n{2}[\r]?)", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(inputString);
String newString = "";
if (m.find()) {
     newString = (m.group().trim());
}
System.out.println(newString);
```

**What is this Regular Expression? - "(.*?\n{2}[\r]?)"**

- `(` : **Capturing Group #1 (start)** - Groups multiple tokens together and
  creates a capture group for extracting a substring or using a
  backreference. This is the open parentheses indicating the start of a group.
- `.`  : **Dot** - Matches any character *except* linebreaks.
- `*` : **Quantifier** - Matches 0 or more of the preceding token.
- `?` : **Lazy** - Makes the preceding quantifier lazy, causing it to
  match as few characters as possible. By default, quantifiers are
  greedy, and will match as many characters as possible.
- `\n` : **Escaped Character** - Matches a LINE FEED character (char
  code 10).
- `{2}` : **Quantifier** - Matches the specified quantity of the
  previous token. For example, {1,3} will match 1 to 3. {3} will match
  exactly 3. {3,} will match 3 or more.
- `[` : **Character Set (start)** - Match any character in the set. This open
  Square bracket starts the Character Set.
- `\r`: **Escaped Character** - Contained within the Character Set -
  Matches a CARRIAGE RETURN character (char code 13).
- `]` : **Character Set (end) - Match any character in the set. This
  close    Square bracket ends the Character Set.
- `?` : **Quantifier** - Matches 0 or 1 of the preceding token,
  effectively making it optional. The preceding token would be the `\r`
  contained within the Character Set.
- `)` : **Capturing Group #1 (end)** - Groups multiple tokens together
  and creates a capture group for extracting a substring or using a
  backreference. This is the close parentheses indicating the end of a
  group.

Comment: String inputString = "URL: www.someurl.com\n"
                   + "id:12345678\n"
                   + "dial:+98765432\n"
                   + "code:0192837465\n"
                   + "AccessCode:123456\n"
                   + "password:abc\n"                  
                   + "\n"
                   + "~~~~~~\n"
                   + "some line here\n"
                   + "~~~~~~";
here either both AccessCode and Password will be present or only AccecssCode will present.i need to extract the substring from "URL: www.someurl.com" to AccessCode/Password . how to handle this case

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myString = "URL: www.someurl.com\n" +
            "id:12345678\n" +
            "dial:+98765432\n" +
            "code:0192837465\n" +
            "password:abc\n" +
            "\n" +
            "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n" +
            "some line here\n" +
            "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~";
    String[] split = myString.split("\\n\\n");
    System.out.println(split[0]);
}
```